# How to show duplicates in a UI when searched in google sheets?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am developing a tracking system for candidates

Attached a search button.
But I want a UI to pop up which will show the duplicates if present.
And when one of the duplicates is clicked, it will fill the required details in the form

I have made this.
But the results are the first row which matches the search text in B4

```
function Search()
{

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

  var str = formS.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var values = dataS.getDataRange().getValues(); 

  var valuesFound = false; 

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
    {
    var rowValue = values[i]; 
   
    
    if (rowValue[0] == str) {
           
      formS.getRange("B7").setValue(rowValue[0]) ;
      formS.getRange("B9").setValue(rowValue[1]) ;
      formS.getRange("B11").setValue(rowValue[2]) ;
      formS.getRange("B13").setValue(rowValue[3]) ;
      formS.getRange("E7").setValue(rowValue[4]) ;
      formS.getRange("E9").setValue(rowValue[5]) ;
      formS.getRange("E11").setValue(rowValue[6]) ;
      formS.getRange("E13").setValue(rowValue[7]) ;

      return; 
      
      }
  }

if(valuesFound==false){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("No record found!");
 }

}
```

Comment: So, once you find the first match you copy data to formS.  Do you want to continue searching through values for duplicates of `str`?

Comment: Yes. Someone searched with the first name. But in sheet there are 5 names with the same first name but different last name. So once this happens. Can we do something to open ui showing all the duplicate values from where selecting one will set the specific values in formS

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

You could get all the first name matches and show them in a dialog, numbered so its easier to pick. Once the user picks the name you can fill out the form.

To use a dropdown and pick a name, that would require a custom dialog.  Doable but more complex.

This script is executed from a menu item.

**Data**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Script**

```
function search() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let dataS = spread.getSheetByName("Data");
    let str = "John";
    let values = dataS.getDataRange().getValues();
    let rowValue = values.filter( row => row[0] === str );
    let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    let prompt = "";
    rowValue.forEach( (row,i) => prompt = prompt.concat((i+1).toString(),": ",row[0], " ",row[1],"\n"));
    if( rowValue.length === 0 ) {
      ui.alert("Name not found ["+str+"]");
      return;
    }
    else if( rowValue.length > 1 ) {
      let response = ui.prompt("Pick a name",prompt,ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
      if( response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK ) {
        str = response.getResponseText();
        str = parseInt(str)-1;
        rowValue = rowValue[str];
      }
    }
    else {
      rowValue = rowValue[0];
    }
    ui.alert(rowValue.toString());
    // Now you can fill out your form with rowValue
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Array.filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [SpreadsheetApp Ui prompt](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#prompt(String,String,ButtonSet))

Comment: Great. I will try this and get back

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

So I decided to show how a custom dialog can be used to display a list of names to pick from.  First a Ui dialog is displayed to use a filter name.  If no name is specified all names will be listed.

Using HTMLService a custom dialog is build using the the pushed variable option for an HTM Template.

Once a name is picked from the list google.script.run is used to return the name to the server and the form can be built from there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("My Menu");
  menu.addItem("Test","showTest");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function showTest() {
  try {
    let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    let response = ui.prompt("What name do you want to search for",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if( response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK ) {
      var name = response.getResponseText();
      if( name === "" ) name = "__All";
    }
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let dataS = spread.getSheetByName("Data");
    let data = dataS.getRange(1,1,dataS.getLastRow(),2).getValues();  // Get range A1:B
    if( name !== "__All" ) {
      data = data.filter( row => row[0] === name );
    }
    if( data.length === 0 ) {
      ui.alert("No names mathcing ["+name+"] found");
      return;
    }
    let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('HTML_Test');
    html.data = data;
    html = html.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Show Test");
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(err);
  }
}

function pickName(name) {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let dataS = spread.getSheetByName("Data");
    dataS.getRange(1,5).setValue(name);
    // Build your form here
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**HTML_Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="selectName">
      <? for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <option><?= data[i][0]+" "+data[i][1] ?></option>
      <? } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="buttonOnClick()" value="Submit">
    <script>
      function buttonOnClick() {
        let name = document.getElementById("selectName").value;
        google.script.run.pickName(name);
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Reference**

- [HTMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)
- [HTML Template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [google.script.host](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host)